# Java: unzipping is significantly slower than zipping

Tags: java, file-io, zip

I have some code that zips up a file sends it over the network and then unzips it on the other end. I'm still testing the code and the source and the destination are the same. Zipping up the file takes on the order of a minute. Unzipping the file takes on the order of an hour. I'm think there must be a flaw in my code to have such a large difference. Here's the code to unzip:

```
public String uncompressLocalZip(String filename,String strUUID,ParentEntry pe,boolean bControlFileProgress) {
        final int BUFFER = 2048;
        BufferedOutputStream out  = null;
        ZipInputStream zis = null;

        try {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Constants.conf.getFileDirectory() + Constants.PATH_SEPARATOR + strUUID + Constants.PATH_SEPARATOR + filename);
            zis = new  ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
            ZipEntry entry;
            long totallength = 0;
            long size = 0;
            if (pe !=null)
                size = pe.getSize();


            while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
                // write the files to the disk

                File fileOutput = new File(Constants.conf.getFileDirectory() + Constants.PATH_SEPARATOR + strUUID + Constants.PATH_SEPARATOR + Constants.conf.getUncompressFolderName() + Constants.PATH_SEPARATOR + entry.getName());
                new File(fileOutput.getParent()).mkdirs();


                BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput));

                out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
                while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                       out.write(data, 0, count);
                       totallength += count;

            }
            out.flush();

        }

     }
     catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return("FAILED");
     }
     finally {
        try {if ( out!= null) out.close();} catch (IOException ioe) {}
        try {if ( zis!= null) zis.close();} catch (IOException ioe) {}

     }

    return("SUCCESS");      



}
```

Here's the code to zip:

```
public void createLocalZip(String filename,ProcessEntry pe) {
    ZipOutputStream out=null;
    try {

        File fileOutput = new File (filename);
        out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileOutput)));
        long totallength=0;
        long size = pe.getParentEntry().getSize();

        String strStartDirectory;
        if (pe.getParentEntry().isDirectory())
            strStartDirectory=pe.getParentEntry().getUrl();
        else
            strStartDirectory=pe.getParentEntry().getFolder();



        for (int i=0;i<pe.getParentEntry().tableModel3.getRowCount();i++) {
            FileEntry fe = pe.getParentEntry().tableModel3.getFileEntry(i);
            File fileInput = new File (fe.getUrl());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileInput);
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input);

            String strRelativeDir = fe.getUrl().substring(strStartDirectory.length()+1,fe.getUrl().length());

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(strRelativeDir);

            out.putNextEntry(entry);


            byte[] bbuf = new byte[2048];
            int length=0;




             while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {

                    out.write(bbuf,0,length);
                    totallength += length;
                    pe.setProgress((int) (totallength*100/size));

             }

             in.close();


        }






    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {if (out!=null) out.close();} catch(IOException ioe){}
    }


}
```

Update: The compression ratio for this particular test is about 90% (1.2GB down to about 100MB). So I suppose it could be the extra writing to disk for unzipping vs. zipping, although I would expect close to a 10X differential vs 60X.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your unzip code at all?

Comment: how long does unzipping the same file take when you run it from the command line (jar or unzip)?

Comment: Also, try to observe the memory usage. Could it be that your system is swapping much, since your file does not fit into memory, and somehow your program tries to have it there?

Comment: @Thilo: it takes about 3 minutes to unzip the file from windows.

Comment: @Paulo - The memory utilization is not excessive. The memory usage for the JVM doing the uncompressing stays around 17MB.

Comment: `BUFFER = 2048;` Why such a small buffer?  I'd try 2^16 (`65536`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't double wrap your OutputStream with BufferedOutputStream (you only need 1 BufferedOutputStream wrapper), and close it after you are done writing to it.

also, `ZipEntry`s can be directories, so check that and handle accordingly.

Comment: Almost all examples I've seen suggest using a bufferedoutputstream (like this one http://www.javadb.com/write-to-file-using-bufferedoutputstream), otherwise the file i/o is not as efficient (I think there is some overhead with each write to disk and buffering reduces the overhead).

Comment: @opike - you are using _2_ BufferedOutputStreams, you only need _1_.

Comment: Buffering twice should not result in slower reading of input.  The cause must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have no really big file to test your code, so I can only guess.

1. You say your uncompressed zip size is more than 1 GB. This could be more than fits in your memory, and if something forces the VM to fit everything in memory, it will have to swap.  Observe your program with a profiler.
2. Make sure your close each FileOutputStream after writing to it. (You create lots of them, and only close the last one.)
3. I'm not sure about the ZipInputStream implementation (maybe it forces your BufferedStream to buffer much of data). You could try `ZipFile` instead (which allows random access, basically).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a specialized library to do the zipping/unzipping. http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/ might help.